# $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} < e \ln \ln (n)$ is true?

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, riemann-hypothesis, divisors-multiples, arithmetic-functions

In Guy Robin, *Grandes valeurs de la fonction somme des diviseurs et hypothèse de Riemann*, J. Math. Pures Appl. **63** (1984), 187–213 ([pdf](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/Robin_1984.pdf))
we find the following result:

> If the Riemann hypothesis is true and $n ≥ 5041$,
> $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} < e^\gamma \ln \ln (n)$

We also know that $e^\gamma < e$. Now my question here is:

**Question:** Without using the Riemann hypothesis, is it possible to show that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} <  e \ln \ln (n)$ ?

Comment: Aleksander Grytczuk, Upper bound for sum of divisors function and the Riemann Hypothesis, Tsukuba J. Math. vol. 31 No. 1 (2007), 67–75, proved if $m$ is odd, $m>(1/2)3^9$, then $\sigma(2m)/(2m)<(39/40)e^{\gamma}\log\log2m$. See https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tkbjm/1496165115

Comment: @The Company , I wish that i didn't change the meaning of your question .

Comment: This makes me want to define the "Robin constant" $R$ as the infimum of the $C>0$ such that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}<e^{C}\log\log n, n\geq 5041$.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik you have introduced the condition $n\ge5041$, which was not in the original question.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own questions.

Answer (score 19):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) says Robin proved unconditionally that the inequality $${\sigma(n)\over n}<e^{\gamma}\log\log n+{0.6483\over\log\log n}$$ holds for all $n\ge3$. I believe this is in the same paper as the one cited in the body of the question.

Comment: Tks!  $e^{\gamma} \ln \ln (n) + \frac{0.6483}{ \ln \ln (n)} < e  \ln \ln (n)$  for all $n>9$

Comment: When said unconditionally, does it imply that it does not depend on HR?

Comment: Yes. "Unconditionally" means not depending on any unproven statements (and that would include the Riemann Hypothesis, which I assume is what you mean by "HR"). But as you're interested in this, why not get the paper, and see for yourself?

Comment: thanks, it has been difficult to find the bibliographical references of G. Robin!

Comment: Huh? The full bibliographical reference is in the body of the question.

Comment: This reference is the result of several investigations by G. Robin.

To say "unconditionally" it refers to 3 more articles which are not easily found.

Comment: You may find https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93803/where-can-i-find-the-paper-by-guy-robin interesting, and also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155225/step-by-step-derivation-of-robins-inequality-sigman-e-gamma-n-log-log